# Gitlab CI gradle test test database error

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, gitlab-ci

Following is my .gitlab-ci.yml.

```
image: java:8

stages:
    - build
    - test
    - deploy

build project:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew build -x test
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 hour
    paths:
      - build/libs/*.jar

test project:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ./gradlew test
```

And following is my application properties for testing location in `src/test/resources/application-test.properties`

```
server.port=8085
spring.application.name=Project Test

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.h2.console.enabled=false
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

## Liquibase migration
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/migrations/db.changelog-master.xml
```

But pipeline always fails on test stage with following error:

```
> Task :test
 MedcareApplicationTests > contextLoads() FAILED
     java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132
         Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796
             Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException at SpringLiquibase.java:316
                 Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException at SQLError.java:174
                     Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException at NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:-2
                         Caused by: java.net.ConnectException at PlainSocketImpl.java:-2
```

I tried with Mysql test database too, but no luck. 
I'm unable to see reports because it's generated inside container, I think. Stuck on these whole day, any help or hint is appreciated.

Comment: didi you find out anything to figure it out ?

Comment: Nope, I couldn't figure out still)

Comment: I also getting this same error.

Comment: May you can get idea https://gitlab.com/letsknow101/springboot-demo-maven/-/issues/1